# Validação do Campo "Pessoa e Grupo"

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Olá,

Estou usando o formulário padrão do Sharepoint, e quero fazer uma validação em um campo do tipo "pessoa ou grupo", basicamente o formulário de edição não pode salvar se este campo estiver em branco.
já tentei por algumas formas, mas pelo que entendi com esse tipo de campo não é tão fácil assim de se "trabalhar" com ele.
o Código abaixo é o que estou usando atualmente para outros tipos de campos um Select e um Input em ambos já estão funcionando.

```
 function PreSaveAction() { 
    var camp1 = $("select[title='camp1'] option:selected").val();
    var camp2 = $("input[title='camp2']").val();
        if(camp1 == "" || camp2 == "")
        {        
            alert("Os Campos 'camp1', 'camp2' não podem ficar em branco.");          
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,
Este tipo de campo é chato mesmo para manipular.
Dê uma olhada aqui https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239930/people-picker-validation

Abs

Comment: Certinho Vlw...